# Can't declare a double array?

Tags: python, c++, arrays, visual-studio

I'm using Python 2.7, C++ and Visual Studio 2017.

I'm working today with this library https://github.com/lava/matplotlib-cpp

The matplotlibcpp.h has multiple method definitions. In line 1469, they define inline ginput like this:

```
inline std::vector<std::array<double, 2>> ginput(const int numClicks = 1, const std::map<std::string, std::string>& keywords = {}){
PyObject *args = PyTuple_New(1);
PyTuple_SetItem(args, 0, PyLong_FromLong(numClicks));

// construct keyword args
PyObject* kwargs = PyDict_New();
for(std::map<std::string, std::string>::const_iterator it = keywords.begin(); it != keywords.end(); ++it)
{
    PyDict_SetItemString(kwargs, it->first.c_str(), PyUnicode_FromString(it->second.c_str()));
}

PyObject* res = PyObject_Call(
    detail::_interpreter::get().s_python_function_ginput, args, kwargs);

Py_DECREF(kwargs);
Py_DECREF(args);
if (!res) throw std::runtime_error("Call to ginput() failed.");

const size_t len = PyList_Size(res);
std::vector<std::array<double, 2>> out;
out.reserve(len);
std::array<double, 2> position;
for (size_t i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    PyObject *current = PyList_GetItem(res, i);

    position[0] = PyFloat_AsDouble(PyTuple_GetItem(current, 0));
    position[1] = PyFloat_AsDouble(PyTuple_GetItem(current, 1));
    out.push_back(position);
}
Py_DECREF(res);

return out;
}
```

I'm getting problems with the `std::array<double, 2> position;` line. I get an error:

> an inconcrete type is not allowed

This is the output when I try to compile. It's in spanish.

```
> 1>------ Operación Compilar iniciada: proyecto: ConsoleApplication2, configuración: Release x64 ------
1>mainAux.cpp
1>c:\users\lraulmn\source\repos\consoleapplication2\consoleapplication2\matplotlibcpp.h(595): warning C4244: 'argumento': conversión de 'const double' a 'long'; posible pérdida de datos
1>c:\users\lraulmn\source\repos\consoleapplication2\consoleapplication2\matplotlibcpp.h(1491): error C2079: 'position' utiliza class 'std::array<double,2>' sin definir
1>c:\users\lraulmn\source\repos\consoleapplication2\consoleapplication2\matplotlibcpp.h(1495): error C2109: el subíndice requiere una matriz o tipo de puntero
1>c:\users\lraulmn\source\repos\consoleapplication2\consoleapplication2\matplotlibcpp.h(1496): error C2109: el subíndice requiere una matriz o tipo de puntero
1>c:\users\lraulmn\source\repos\consoleapplication2\consoleapplication2\matplotlibcpp.h(1497): error C2664: 'void std::vector<std::array<double,2>,std::allocator<_Ty>>::push_back(_Ty &&)': el argumento 1 no puede convertirse de 'int' a 'const _Ty &'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Ty=std::array<double,2>
1>        ]
1>c:\users\lraulmn\source\repos\consoleapplication2\consoleapplication2\matplotlibcpp.h(1497): note: Razón: no se puede realizar la conversión de 'int' a 'const _Ty'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Ty=std::array<double,2>
1>        ]
1>c:\users\lraulmn\source\repos\consoleapplication2\consoleapplication2\matplotlibcpp.h(1497): note: Uso del tipo no definido 'std::array<double,2>'
1>c:\users\lraulmn\source\repos\consoleapplication2\consoleapplication2\matplotlibcpp.h(1469): note: vea la declaración de 'std::array<double,2>'
1>Compilación del proyecto "ConsoleApplication2.vcxproj" terminada -- ERROR.
========== Compilar: 0 correctos, 1 incorrectos, 0 actualizados, 0 omitidos ==========
```

I'll put a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/16KbO.png) anyways so you can read it better.

I think I'm missing a library or an include in the visual studio properties as that line has correct syntax as far as I know and also people are not reporting this error. I hope this is easy to solve for someone! Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm assuming "utiliza class 'std::array<double,2>' sin definir" means that you're trying to use the class `std::array` without having defined it first, so you should include the standard header file where it's defined. Try including the `<array>` header, as [shown in the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/standard-library/array-class-stl?view=vs-2017).

Comment: literally that. As it was working in other places, like lines before I thought it was included. Post it as a comment so I can valid your solution. Thanks! @ForceBru

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the file on GitHub does use `std::array`, but doesn't include the [`array` standard header](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/standard-library/array-class-stl?view=vs-2017).

Including it solved the issue.